# How to make fillPolygon(s) behined JButtom

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

[Strange rendering]
First of all sorry for my english.
I got a strange rendering bug: fillPolygon rendered in front of the 2. and 3. JButton and if I move the mouse over the buttons the rendering suddenly turns to correct. I'm not sure what's the problem.
I make a BufferedImage filled with stars (also i tryed without of BufferedImage).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIf88.png]

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0 , 0, null );
}
```

The buttons setup:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton(names[i]);
        buttons[i].setFont(font);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(al);
        buttons[i].setActionCommand(actionCommands[i]);
        buttons[i].setVisible(defaultButtonVisibility[i]);
    }
```

The panel settup:

```
private void panelSetup(Color background) {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(getSize());
    panel.setBackground(background);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) panel.add(buttons[i], gbc);
    makeBackground();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0 , 0, null );
}
```

When you do custom painting, you should be overriding the paintComponent() method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0 , 0, null );
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html).

You will see that the component and all its children are painted, and then you attempt to paint an image on top of them. For a background you need to paint the background of the panel first, and then paint the child components.

> if I move the mouse over the buttons the rendering suddenly turns to correct.

This is because the button needs to be repainted to reflect the "rollover" effect. So the button is temporarily painted over top of the background.

However, try resizing the frame and the background will appear again, because the entire frame get repainted.

Comment: @Xeno Do not forget that this is [what you should do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Is that mean I had to make an extends of JPanel and using that just for a background?